# How to distribute a key to each item of a vector in clojure?

Tags: clojure

What function could I use so that if I do :

`(the-function :a [1 2 3 4 5])`

I get :
`[{:a 1} {:a 2} {:a 3} {:a 4} {:a 5}]`

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to express this:

```
user> (defn the-function [key vals] (map hash-map (repeat key) vals)) 
#'user/the-function    
user> (the-function :a [1 2 3 4 5])      
({:a 1} {:a 2} {:a 3} {:a 4} {:a 5})
```

or

```
user> (defn the-function [key vals] (map (partial hash-map key)  vals))
#'user/the-function
user> (the-function :a [1 2 3 4 5])
({:a 1} {:a 2} {:a 3} {:a 4} {:a 5})
```

or using for instead of map:

```
user> (defn the-function [key vals] (for [val vals] {key val}))
#'user/the-function
user> (the-function :a [1 2 3 4 5])
({:a 1} {:a 2} {:a 3} {:a 4} {:a 5})
```

These return sequences, and if it needs to be a vector you can wrap them in a call to `vec` or use mapv:

```
user> (defn the-function [key vals] (mapv (partial hash-map key)  vals))
#'user/the-function
user> (the-function :a [1 2 3 4 5])
[{:a 1} {:a 2} {:a 3} {:a 4} {:a 5}]
user> (the-function :a `(1 2 3 4 5))
[{:a 1} {:a 2} {:a 3} {:a 4} {:a 5}]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for : `(mapv (partial hash-map key)  vals)` Thank you Arthur!!

Comment: Also : `(defn the-function [k vs] (vec (for [v vs] {k v})))`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by simply using map:

```
(map (fn [v] {:a v}) [1 2 3 4 5]) ;; ({:a 1} {:a 2} {:a 3} {:a 4} {:a 5})
```

Is this what you're looking for?

You can then wrap this logic in a function of course - provided you use it often enough.